# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{x\left[1\over x\right]}$. Am I correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{x\left[1\over x\right]}$.

*Attempt*: $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{x\left[1\over x\right]}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}x\left ({1\over x}-\{{1\over x}\}\right)=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\left (1-{x\{{1\over x}\}}\right).$

Since $\{{1\over x}\}$ is bounded and $x\to 0$, then $x\cdot\{{1\over x}\}\to 0$ and therefore $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{x\left[1\over x\right]}=1.$

Comment: Almost. Cross off the thing you said goes to zero in your limit on that second line there. What's left?

Comment: Looks great now.

Comment: Isn't it correct that $x\cdot\{{1\over x}\}\to 0$?
And I changed my final result...

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if $x<0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach using sandwich:
$$x\left(\frac1x-1\right)<x\left[\frac1x\right]\le x\frac1x$$