# Is $\{-{a\over b}\}=\{{a\over b}\}$? (Fractional part)

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given $a,b\in \Bbb{N},(a,b)=1$, is $\{-{a\over b}\}=\{{a\over b}\}$? Or it remains $\{-{a\over b}\}$?

The tags I added are the result of me:

1. Not being sure where the notations came from.
2. Assuming that whoever is acquainted with the tags, might have a clue regarding the issue.

Comment: What is $\{{a\over b}\}$ here? A *set* with a single element  $a \over b$ or the *fractional part* of a number as in your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168751/find-lim-limitsx-to-0x-left1-over-x-right-am-i-correct?

Comment: That is the fractional part. That is why I am wondering, whether or not, a minus takes a part in the fractional part.

Comment: $\{ x \} = x - [ x ]$ holds for *all* real numbers (including the negative numbers). So $\{ -x \}$ and $\{ x \}$ are usually different.

Comment: If you had tried even ONE example, you could have answered the question yourself :-(

Comment: I am getting my examples messed up.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ for all real numbers $x$. Thus, if $\frac{a}b=\frac{n}2$ for some integer $n$, $\left\{\frac{a}b\right\}=\left\{-\frac{a}b\right\}$: both are $0$ if $n$ is even, and both are $\frac{1}2$ if $n$ is odd.

In fact you should try to prove that if $\frac{a}b$ is not an integer, then $\left\{\frac{a}b\right\}+\left\{-\frac{a}b\right\}=1$. (A few sketches might be very helpful in seeing what's going on.)